# How to remove a hyperlink tag under a header tag using beautifulSoup -

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a webpage. Here I want to extract only Freelancer from the header H3. but when I run the below code I get "More jobs" which is under 'a' tag . How to extract only Freelancer from below link?

https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=work+from+home&txtLocation=

my code is:

```
company_name = job.find('h3', class_='joblist-comp-name').text
```

Result is:  Freelancer (More Jobs)

Expected: Freelancer

Comment: I am getting  this ParserError: Document is empty

Comment: It appears that the URL you posted is incomplete (missing a location value). Please update your question with a working URL so that others can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply split the string based on space and extract the first text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""<h3 class="joblist-comp-name">Freelancer <a class="jobs-frm-comp" href="/candidate/companySearchResult.html?from=submit&encid=V1VUNYG9OfxywnPTmYOKIg==&searchType=byCompany&luceneResultSize=25">(More Jobs)</h3>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
soup.find("h3",class_="joblist-comp-name").text.split(" ")[0]
```

Output:

```
'Freelancer'
```

Update with URL given

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=work+from+home&txtLocation=")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
```

Here it will find main `ul` tag and from it find all `li` tag so it will return as list from that we can go for first element and we can find the text associate to it!

```
all_li=soup.find("ul",class_="new-joblist").find_all("li")
all_li[0].find("h3",class_="joblist-comp-name").get_text(strip=True).split("(")[0]
```

Output:

```
'Freelancer'
```

Comment: I am getting the empty string not getting any out put

Comment: can you share the exact URL you are working on because above code run successfully based on html provide by you!

Comment: https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=work+from+home&txtLocation=

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not well formed, but if it's fixed like this:

```
<h3 class="joblist-comp-name"> Freelancer 
  <a class="jobs-frm-comp" href="/whatever">  More Jobs</a>
</h3>
```

something like the below should get you there - it uses the lxml library and xpath search to zero in on the target. Obviously, you'll have to modify it to fit your actual html:

```
import lxml.html as lh
company = """the modified html string above"""
job = lh.fromstring(company)
job.xpath('//h3[@class="joblist-comp-name"]/text()')[0].strip()
```

Output:

```
'Freelancer'
```

Comment: I am getting the empty sting